# Looping through a JSON array in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to loop through a JSON array which I am getting from an HTTP Request, but I am not sure how.

What I have tried is this:

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL, cachePolicy: NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.returnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){
    request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL, cachePolicy: NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity);
}
let session = URLSession.shared
var getResp = false

var zinnen : [Zin] = []
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest,
                            completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
                                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                                for case let data in json {
                                    if let zin = Zin(json: data) {
                                        zinnen.append(zin)
                                    }
                                }
})
task.resume()
```

And this is my struct:

```
struct Zin : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String

    let id : Int
    let dutch_sentence : String
    let polish_sentence : String
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.id = dictionary["id"] as? Int ?? 0
        self.dutch_sentence = dictionary["dutch_sentence"] as? String ?? ""
        self.polish_sentence = dictionary["polish_sentence"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

A sample of the JSON Array:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"35",
      "dutch_sentence":"Ja",
      "polish_sentence":"Tak"
   },
   {  
      "id":"36",
      "dutch_sentence":"Nee",
      "polish_sentence":"Nie"
   }
]
```

But in this I get the error

> Type '[String: Any]??' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

Comment: `let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any]` => `let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [[String: Any]]` You JSON is an Array of Dictionaries, not a Dictionary so the for loop is weird for a dictionary.

Comment: use the codable protocol instead of parsing the JSON manually. see https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/

Comment: @Larme That changed my error from Type '[String: Any]??' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence' to Type '[[String: Any]]??' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

Comment: Thanks @Scriptable I will look in to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ignore the error! Both `try?` and optional downcast cause a nested optional (`Optional<Optional<[String:Any]>>`) which of course is not a sequence, not even when being casted to an array.

Handle the error, optional bind the result and cast the result to the more specified **array** `[[String:String]]`. According to the JSON the value for `id` is `String` not `Int`.

```
do {
   if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String: String]] {
      for zinData in json {
          let zin = Zin(dictionary: zinData)
          zinnen.append(zin)
      }
   }
} catch { print(error) }
```

PS: The initializer in the `Zin` class does not match the initializer in the parsing code. I'm using the version of the class. You have to change the type of `id` from `Int` to `String`

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem! And you are right I was thinking because it's a number I should use it but it's a string in the JSON.

Comment: Reading JSON is very easy and straightforward. Every value in double quotes is a string, period. There are no exceptions.